# Can I use Axios and Fetch in the same Reactjs application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am beginner and i would like to know if I can use Axios and Fetch in the same Reactjs application?
For exemple Axios for sending email and Fetch for additional requests..

Comment: Yes you can, both are completely independent and don't interfere with each other

Comment: Don't, though. It just adds to the cognitive overload, as their APIs are different.

Comment: jonrsharpe is right, if you have the choice, choose one and go with it. There are no reasons to use both.

Comment: Yeap. You can do it but it's generally not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use both, its totally up to you. You can also create different helpers according to your needs. As axios also provides onUploadProgress which can be useful for showing the current progress of the request.

For documentation you can check :

-> fetch https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch

-> axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios